# Function pointers returns different class type

Tags: c++, glew

I'm trying to write a little class that uses the GLEW and I'm in front of a stone wall because I don't understand how to bypass a problem that the compiler is giving me.

Using this code inside VS2012 Express

```
void OpenGlRendering::InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(
        GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
        GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );

    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(OpenGlRendering::ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
    glutTimerFunc(0, TimerFunction, 0);
    glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyboardFunction);
}  

void OpenGlRendering::ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}
void OpenGlRendering::IdleFunction(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I've got this compiler error:

> IntelliSense: argument of type "void (OpenGlRendering::***)(int Width,
>   int Height)" is incompatible with the parameter type "void (*)(int,
>   int)"

Before using some classes to clean up the mess in the code it was vorking fine because the function was residing in the main.cpp declared as a plain function

```
void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}
```

and was called like this

```
glutReshapeFunc(OpenGlRendering::ResizeFunction);
```

Comment: You can't pass a member function pointer as an argument to something that expects a non-member function pointer without using some bind methods.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

Comment: Adding to previous comments, you can either make the member function static (if you intend this class as a utility library this might make sense, otherwise, might not), or create a wrapper function that will encapsulate the call to a particular instance, as described in the link from @ThomasFenzl.

Comment: This class is meant as a utility class; thanks all very much, now I've got my mind a little bit clearer on how this type of objects are saved and used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call pointers to non-static member functions they implicitly need/provide a hidden argument (the `this`-pointer to an instance of the class). You cannot mix static functions and non-static member functions because of this hidden argument. This is what you are trying to do.

```
void (OpenGlRendering::*)(int Width, int Height)
```

is a non-static member function, which is incompatible with a static function

```
void (*)(int, int)
```

even though the explicit arguments and return type are equal.